# How to store xml file in oracle database as raw data

Tags: xml, database, oracle, oracle11g

I heavily searched google on "how to store xml file in oracle file".
But, I couldn't find any solution yet.
I want to store a xml file (raw data).  And I don't want BFile.
Please tell me the way to store xml and retrieving from Oracle database.

Thank you.

Comment: Do you mean "how do i load it and read it?" or "what's the most appropriate way to store it?". The answer is probably going to depend on what you want to do with the stored data. Do you want to read the data when it's loaded, or just treat it as a stream of bytes? And what's your exact Oracle version?

Answer (score 0):

To store the XML file you can use a column of type BLOB. This will just store the data for you. To access the XML file using PLSQL you use BFILE. You can then load the file into the BLOB column.

Here are some examples:
http://dwarehouse.wordpress.com/2011/06/15/loading-and-unloading-files-using-oracle-database/

Alternatively you can use any method your client programming language provides.

Answer (score 0):

#### Selecting Attributes Values From external XML

You can extract values from any tag inside external XML file and insert into database but you will face some problems, from my experience with oracle please take care from the following :

- oracle has configuration file contains some default namespaces so if you have any namespaces in your xml file otherwise these namespaces , you have to add it in the procedure or function you build
- if you select from XML (BLOB or CLOB files) dont forget to convert the result to BLOB or CLOB as formatted in xml.

Here is an example of procedure updates table with values retured from XML file :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE procedure Test(FileName in  varchar,URN_Par in varchar)
is
begin
update Test
set File_Name =(
------------------this step get value of tag (file_name) and update test table , also you have to write any namespaces in as below    
select 
    extract(column_value, '//File_Name/text()','xmlns="http://tempuri.org/')
  from
    table(xmlsequence(xmltype(bfilename('GIDTEMPFILES',FileName) ,
      nls_charset_id('AL16UTF8')))))
    , Class_Name =(
     select 
    extract(column_value, '//Class_Name/text()','xmlns="http://tempuri.org/')
  from
    table(xmlsequence(xmltype(bfilename('GIDTEMPFILES',FileName) ,
      nls_charset_id('AL16UTF8')))))
    , Document_Date =(
     select 
    extract(column_value, '//Document_Date/text()','xmlns="http://tempuri.org/')
  from
    table(xmlsequence(xmltype(bfilename('GIDTEMPFILES',FileName) ,
      nls_charset_id('AL16UTF8')))))
     , Image =(
-------------return the value stored in the image tag as clob to column image in DB which is clob
    select 
    extract(column_value, '//Image/text()','xmlns="http://tempuri.org/').GetClobVal()
  from
    table(xmlsequence(xmltype(bfilename('GIDTEMPFILES',FileName) ,
      nls_charset_id('AL16UTF8')))))
    where URN = URN_par;
    end;
```